# For CSS, why 2 floats in a table cell don't float on the same level?

Tags: html, css

If two divs are floated in a table cell, and the text are short, they float nicely on the same level.

But when the second div has longer text, the 2 divs now don't float on the same level.

Why is that and how to make it work, **without specifying a hard-coded width for the 2nd div?**  (because dynamic width is needed if other table cells are wider or not as wide)

A code example is in:
http://topics2look.com/code-examples/two-floats-in-a-table/

The first hello is floated left (it actually is supposed to be an image of `+` or `-` using CSS image sprite, but just made simple here).  The "world world" is supposed to be the description and float nicely next to the image.

So the first table is all ok.  But in the second table, it has "world world world ... world" and is quite long.  Now the second div will not float next to it but will float under the first float.  Is there a way to make it shrink wrap better so that it floats nicely next to the first div?

Comment: What do you mean, "on the same level"?

Comment: see the sample page and you will know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't float the second div, then add `overflow: hidden;` (or auto) to it to make is anew block formatting context, should achieve what you need:

**CSS:**

```
body { 
   font: 16px Verdana, sans-serif;
}

#main-content { 
   width: 600px; 
   border: 6px double black; 
   margin: 20px 0;
}
table { 
   border: 6px double orange;
}

table div { 
   float: left; 
   padding: 4px;
}

table div+div {
   float: none; 
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td><div>hello</div> <div>world world world world world world world world world</div></td>
      <td><div>hello</div> <div>world world world world world world world</div></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: nice, guess what while I am beginning to take a nap I thought about the same thing: if all I care is the stationary part of the image, why not just float that one and let the other content "flow around" it.  I also modified in a similar way and put on http://topics2look.com/code-examples/two-floats-in-a-table/solution.html

Comment: why do you set `overflow:hidden` for the second div?  I also have one in my solution for the `td`, but because I remembered it is better to "clear the float" and used that newer method to clear it.

Comment: I put your solution on http://topics2look.com/code-examples/two-floats-in-a-table/solution1.html   if the `table div+div` has `overflow:hidden` it wrapped more than necessary (tested on Chrome)... without it, it let the word go across in one line

Comment: by the way, your double border makes it look more neat.  My dashed border makes it look messy.  on the other hand, I wonder if program manager sees the dash, he knows it is in development and won't give any comment that it is not good.  but if he sees the double border which looks neat, he may be more likely to complain why the content inside isn't perfect yet.  but if I do development myself, I think I would rather use double border.

Comment: don't really understand all your comment but the reason for overflow: hidden on the second div is to stop the "worlds" from wrapping under the word "hello" - you don't need it on the `td` as they already naturally contain floats ;) - glad it helped though :)

Answer (score 0):

Any element that you float becomes a block-level element. That's why when the two blocks are too wide to sit next to each other the second block floats under the first one.

I don't know that there is a solution in this case without setting the width of the elements, but I am curious to know what you're trying to achieve with this.

Comment: well, the first float contains a div with a `+` or `-` image using CSS sprite as background.  The second div is the text.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there's a better way to accomplish what you are trying to do. I am also curious what your goal is here; floats work exactly this way for good reason.

If you absolutely must have them resize dynamically in this paradigm, you could always use javascript.